# WebAudio LinearRampToValueAtTime isn't ramping

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I've been working in WebAudio trying to ramp a oscillator node on and off. I've been trying to verify the ramping on the signal with an oscilloscope, and noticing that the linear ramp (from linearRampToValueAtTime() function) is not working as anticipated.

First, I'm unable to change the duration of the ramping and then when I manage to get a ramp, it is not linear (using setValueAtTime() function).

So I guess my question is this - has anyone been able to validate using external equipment that the ramps are working in Chrome?

I tried verifying the example listed on the MDN documentation site:
https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/audio-param/

but those demos also don't ramp - is this an issue with my audio driver, web browser, or some other issue? I'm assuming there's something wrong in the implementation, because it's not working anywhere, and others don't seem to have this issue so any help I can get would be appreciated!

snippets of the code below:

Creating nodes

```
 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        oscCarrier[i] = audioCtx.createOscillator();
        panOsc[i] = audioCtx.createStereoPanner();
        gainOsc[i] = audioCtx.createGain();

        oscCarrier[i].frequency.value = 1000;
        gainOsc[i].gain.setValueAtTime(0,audioCtx.currentTime);

        oscCarrier[i].connect(panOsc[i]);
        panOsc[i].connect(gainOsc[i])
        gainOsc[i].connect(audioCtx.destination)

        oscCarrier[i].start();
}
```

for ramping off:

```
    let rampTime = .025 //(25 ms ramp off)
     gainOsc[channel].gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime + rampTime)
```

for ramping on:

```
    let rampTime = .025 //(25 ms ramp on)
     gainOsc[channel].gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime + rampTime)
```

Comment: re: The demo ramping site - I get the following error when I open up the console and try to use a ramp or play the audio (the audio plays, but my guess is the ramping is halted by this process:
 Uncaught ReferenceError: MediaElementSourceNode is not defined
    at HTMLAudioElement.<anonymous> ((index):65:22)

Comment: I found the issue with the demo site - they use MediaElementSourceNode, but the element is MediaElementAudioSourceNode, so there's a bug on the demo page for linear ramping.